# hhvm unix socket owned by root but need to change to nginx

Tags: hhvm

I am able to run hhvm with usual tcp port 9000 but I want nginx and hhvm to communicate through a unix socket but the problem is that the socket defaults to root:root and I have to manually change it with chown every time it restarts. I run a minimal installation of CentOS7 and have previously used php-fpm but you have the option to select user for socket there, but not in hhvm it seems, I'm not sure. Any ideas?

/etc/hhvm/server.ini

```
pid = /var/run/hhvm/pid                          

hhvm.server.ip = 127.0.0.1                       
;hhvm.server.port = 9000                         
hhvm.server.file_socket = /var/run/hhvm/hhvm.sock
hhvm.server.type = fastcgi                       
hhvm.server.default_document = index.php         
hhvm.source_root = /srv/www/public_html          
hhvm.server.always_use_relative_path = false     
hhvm.server.thread_count = 32                    
hhvm.resource_limit.max_socket = 65536           

hhvm.jit = true                                  
hhvm.jit_a_size = 67108864                       
hhvm.jit_a_stubs_size = 22554432                 
hhvm.jit_global_data_size = 22554432             

; mysql                                          
hhvm.mysql.socket = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock    
hhvm.mysql.typed_results = true                  

; logging                                        
hhvm.log.use_syslog = false                      
hhvm.log.use_log_file = true                     
hhvm.log.file = /var/log/hhvm/error.log          
hhvm.log.level = Warning                         
hhvm.log.always_log_unhandled_exceptions = true  
hhvm.log.runtime_error_reporting_level = 8191
```

/usr/lib/systemd/system/hhvm.service

```
[Unit]
Description=HipHop Virtual Machine (FCGI)

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/hhvm -c /etc/hhvm/server.ini -c /etc/hhvm/php.ini --user hhvm --mode daemon -vServer.Type=fastcgi -vServer.FileSocket=/var/run/hhvm/hhvm.sock

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must manually change the file owership AFTER it has been created by HHVM.

Or use TCP mode instead of unix sock.

In my Docker, I have a service like:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e

# @todo this is horrible (but HHVM is creating socket as root user)

while [ ! -S /var/run/php5-fpm.sock ]
do
  usleep 1
done

chown www-data /var/run/php5-fpm.sock

sv stop fix_socket_perms
```

To do so.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify user in `/etc/hhvm/server.ini`, add line

```
hhvm.server.user = nginx
```

Change `nginx` to your nginx user if needed and restart `hhvm`

```
sudo service hhvm restart
```

Comment: Tried, but still running as root.

Comment: this is a known issue :/ since you can use TCP, this is not "blocking" so I believe this is not consider as a bug by HHVM team. (even if I totally agree this is very very *******)